# Ubuntu sometime has lost connection to usb thumbdrive bootable device

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

need your help to advise for my problem.

my machine config : CPU Intel Celeron coffee lake 4 Gb ram, bios AMI

my ubuntu config : Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-47

my problem is, sometimes my machine lost connection from usb bootable device, after rebooting, the machine cannot find bootable device.
i tried to check with plugged secondary bootable usb device that contain EFi shell. after duplicate the issue, i check on efi shell, there is no my primary usb bootable on the device list.

is it, any possibility this come from on the process shutting down the machine. i mean, like when shut down process, there is any error that make the bootable usb is become not visible from the machine/ lost connection?